# How to use re.match to find the first part of an URL?

Tags: python, regex, match

I am in the process of using "urllib.request.urlopen(URL)" to find the size of different files on different servers. The problem is that I need to authenticate myself. This I do through the following.

```
url = "https://abc123-abca93.xxx.xxxx.se/other_parts_of_url/file.tar"
top_level_url = "https://abc123-abca93.xxx.xxxx.se/"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, 'username',password.get())
handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
```

This works such that I can now access the file when I do

```
filesize = urllib.requests.urlopen(url).headers._headers[8][1]
```

But the problem is that the URL will change for each file so I want to use RegExp to find the first part of the URL, that is

```
"https://"+more_characters+".se"+possibly_port_number+"/"
```

I was thinking that I could use re.match, but I am not sure how to write the correct logic for this case, is it possible to do for instance something like

```
match = re.match("https://" + any amount of characters +"/", url)
```

Comment: Hello, Can you tell me why you want to use regex whereas you can split the string and compare it?

Comment: Well I suppose I could use split as well, it feels like regex would give a more compact solution. If I would use split I would do something like "a = url.split("/") " and I would have to look for what index contains the ".se" string and then put the string together replacing each instance of " " with "/" due to the split. Seems a bit tedious.

Comment: Assuming all hosts are going to belong to ```.se``` top level domain and if you still want to use a regex, this one can help: ```r'^.*:[/]{2}(.*\.se)[:/].*$'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `urllib`'s parsing capabilities:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = "https://abc123-abca93.xxx.xxxx.se/other_parts_of_url/file.tar"

parse_result = urlparse(url)

top_level_url = parse_result.netloc
```

Comment: netloc will skip the scheme part, this includes it https://stackoverflow.com/a/55360196/3612149

Answer (score 0):

Possible regex:
https://regex101.com/r/GyEFx2/1

Then use:

```
match = re.match(pattern, url)
if match:
    first_part = match.group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, use [URLParse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) for that (python3 [version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html))

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
toplevel = o.scheme + "://" + o.netloc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the plain old `str.split()` for that:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Mar 21 2019, 10:05:02) 
[GCC 9.0.1 20190227 (Red Hat 9.0.1-0.8)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'https://abc123-abca93.xxx.xxxx.se/other_parts_/file.tar'.split('/')
['https:', '', 'abc123-abca93.xxx.xxxx.se', 'other_parts_', 'file.tar']
>>>
```